# Pass object instance to Roslyn ScriptEngine

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm looking for a C# scripting engine, that can interpret blocks of C# code, while maintaing a context. For example, if enter to it: `var a = 1;` , and then `a + 3`, it'll output `4`.
I'm aware of MS [`Roslyn`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) , which indeed do that, but it's a sandbox (respect to the program that launched it). So, if I create an instance of `ScriptEngine` and an instance of `MyClass` (just an arbirary class of mine) , I have no option to pass a reference of `my_class` to `script_engine`.

Is it possible to somehow **pass that reference**?

What *I'd like* to do, is something like:

```
ScriptEngine engine; // A Roslyn object
Session session // A Roslyn object

MyClass my_class; // My object

// all required initializations

Submission<object> sm = session.CompileSubmission<object>("var a=1;"); 
dynamic result = sm.Execute(); 

Submission<object> sm = session.CompileSubmission<object>("a + 3;"); 
dynamic result = sm.Execute(); // result is now 4

MyClass my_class;
session.AddReferenceToAnOject(my_class); // function that does not exists, but reflect my intention

Submission<object> sm = session.CompileSubmission<object>("my_class.ToString();"); 
dynamic result = sm.Execute();  // result is no the output of my_class.ToString()
```

Please notice that `AddReferenceToAnOject()` is the missing part, as there's no such function in roslyn.

Comment: If I were you, I would remove the second bullet point. That would help preventing your question from being closed as a "recommendation for a tool, library or favorite off-site resource".

Comment: Take a look at CS-Script http://www.csscript.net/

Comment: Maybe check [interacting with the host application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi fixed. Is there a legitimate way to ask the second bullet around here? (in case that the first bullet stays unsolved)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The bullet point is legit if it's another way to do the same thing using the .NET Framework.

Comment: There is another way to do this using Reflection.Emit, if Roslyn does not suit.

Comment: BTW, scripting has been completely removed from the latest version of Roslyn, because of some issues. When/if it's added back, it will probably look different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was found in a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx) commented by @Herman.

As it turn out, Roslyn `ScriptEngine/Session` supports a concept of `Host Object`.
In order to use it, define a class of your choise, and pass it upon session creation. Doing so, makes all *public* member of that host object, available to context inside the session:

```
public class MyHostObject
{
    public List<int> list_of_ints;
    public int an_int = 23;
}

var hostObject = new MyHostObject();
hostObject.list_of_ints = new List<int>();
hostObject.list_of_ints.Add(2);
var engine = new ScriptEngine(new[] { hostObject.GetType().Assembly.Location });

// passing reference to hostObject upon session creation
var session = Session.Create(hostObject);

// prints `24` to console
engine.Execute(@"System.Console.WriteLine(an_int + list_of_ints.Count);", 
               session);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete procedure how to pass variables from object to roslyn dynamic executed code. Included is also eval() wrapper.
First install RoslynSetup.exe from microsoft.com http://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=34685

Then Add Reference Roslyn.Compilers and Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp to your project (Assemblies / extensions)

Here is full working code for C# console app in vs2012.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Scripting;
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;

namespace testRoslyn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestRoslyn tr = new TestRoslyn();
            tr.Test = "this was set from main program ";
            tr.test();
            System.Console.WriteLine(tr.Test);
            tr.Test = "this was set from main program for eval";
            Eval e = new Eval();
            e.create<TestRoslyn>(tr);                           
            e.eval("Test = Test + \" AND THIS WAS SET FROM Eval()\";");
            System.Console.WriteLine(tr.Test);
            string a = e.eval<string>("string a = \"return this from eval\";a");
            System.Console.WriteLine(a);
            tr.Test = "now return this";
            string b = e.eval<string>("string a = Test + \" ... and this\";a");
            System.Console.WriteLine(b);
            double d = e.eval<double>("double dbl = 1.2345*3;dbl");
            System.Console.WriteLine(d);
            e.eval("string testIt(string a){return \"testIt(): \"+a+\"\";}");
            string c = e.eval<string>("string c = testIt(\"nice\");c");
            System.Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class TestRoslyn
    {
        public string Test;

        public TestRoslyn()
        {
        }

        public string test()
        {
            ScriptEngine roslynEngine = new ScriptEngine();
            Roslyn.Scripting.Session session = roslynEngine.CreateSession(this);
            session.AddReference(this.GetType().Assembly);
            session.AddReference("System.Web");
            session.ImportNamespace("System");
            session.ImportNamespace("System.Web");
            var result = (string)session.Execute("Test = Test + \" ... and this was set from roslyn code.\";Test");
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class Eval
    {
        ScriptEngine RoslynEngine = new ScriptEngine();
        Roslyn.Scripting.Session Session;

        public void create<T>(T hostObject = null) where T : class
        {
            RoslynEngine = new ScriptEngine();
            Session = RoslynEngine.CreateSession(hostObject);
            if (hostObject != null)
                Session.AddReference(hostObject.GetType().Assembly);
            Session.AddReference("System.Web");
            Session.ImportNamespace("System");
            Session.ImportNamespace("System.Web");
        }

        public void eval (string strEval)
        {                                                
            Session.Execute(strEval);
        }

        public T eval<T>(string strEval) 
        {
            return (T) Session.Execute(strEval);            
        }
    }
}
```