# Control WPF c# application via script

Tags: c#, wpf, scripting, visual-studio-2015, cs-script

I'm analysing if it is possible to control my application with scripts/macros.

My application is a WPF application written in c#/VS2015 and I'm trying to do the following (pseudo code)

```
public interface IExposedTasks
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> Customers {get; }
    void ShowSum(int sum);
}

public static class Host : IExposedTasks 
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Customers { ... }

    public void ShowSum(int sum)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sum: " + sum.ToString());
    }
}

...

public void ExecuteScript(string script)
{
    // execute script 
}
```

The script should be able to access all data from IExposedTasks and do something like:

```
var sum = 0;

foreach(var customer in Host.Customers) 
{
    sum += customer.Value;
}

Host.ShowSum(sum);
```

The language of the scripts could be in c#, JavaScript or VB.

I have tried to do this with Cs-Script, but it does not seem to work on Win10/VS2015.

COM is not an alternative.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What an internal application of us does is simply accepting arbitrary C#-Code, compiling it on the fly

Comment: Right direction: Roslyn: http://www.jayway.com/2015/05/09/using-roslyn-to-build-a-simple-c-interactive-script-engine/

Comment: @SynerCoder: Thanks, I have read and tested a bit of Roslyn, and there are some samples available on the Internet which describes what I'm looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733556/pass-object-instance-to-roslyn-scriptengine, for example. Unfortunately these examples seems outdated since they are using "other objects" like Session which no longer seems to be supported, so this is not working as it seems.